# Fubini-Study metric in homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $\omega_{st}=\frac{i}{2}\sum_jdz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_j$ denote the standard 2-form on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. The form $\tilde{\omega}=\frac{1}{||z||^2}\omega_{st}$ is invariant under the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action, therefore we should be able to push it down to $\mathbb{P}^n$ and obtain the Fubini-Study form. Moreover, if I understood well we can write an object on  $\mathbb{P}^n$ in homogeneous coordinates if it is invariant under the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action.

I do not understand why in homogeneous coordinates the Fubini-Study form writes
$$\omega_{FS}([z_0:...:z_n])=\frac{i}{2}\sum_j\frac{dz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_j}{||z||^2} -\frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k}\frac{\bar{z}_jz_kdz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_k}{||z||^4} $$
and not simply
$$\omega_{FS}([z_0:...:z_n])=\frac{i}{2}\sum_j\frac{dz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_j}{||z||^2} $$

Answer (score 3):

Being invariant under the "global" $\Bbb C^*$ action as you're thinking of it is not sufficient; you need to allow a different action point by point.  If you take any two local *holomorphic* sections of the $\Bbb C$-bundle $\mathscr O_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$ and pull back $\omega$, you want to get the same $(1,1)$-form. (Think, for example, of what happens on the overlap of two standard holomorphic charts for $\Bbb P^n$.) Thus, you want not $\partial\bar\partial \|z\|^2$, but $\partial\bar\partial \log \|z\|^2$, which is in fact the Kähler form. Note that if $\lambda\colon U\to\Bbb C-\{0\}$ is holomorphic, then $\partial\bar\partial \log(\|\lambda z\|^2) = \partial\bar\partial \log|\lambda|^2 + \partial\bar\partial \log\|z\|^2 = \partial\bar\partial \log\|z\|^2$, as desired.

Comment: I know how to obtain $\omega_{FS}$ as the curvature of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, I wonder how to obtain the desired formula in homogeneous coordinates from the definition of $\omega_{FS}$ as the 2-form (or metric) on $\mathbb{P}^n$ which pulls back to the round metric on $S^{2n+1}$ and to the standard one on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$

Comment: I mentioned $\mathscr O(-1)$ because a local section of $\pi\colon \Bbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}\to\Bbb P^n$ *is* a section of the tautological line bundle. The Fubini-Study metric on $\Bbb P^n$ does *not* pull back to the standard metric on $\Bbb C^{n+1}$. My explanation is the correct one. You need more information other than saying it restricts to the round metric on the sphere; the holomorphic structure as I've discussed is essential.

Comment: On Wikipedia it says that the Fubini-Study metric is the quotient metric of $S^{2n+1}/S^1$ where the sphere is endowed with the restriction of the Euclidean metric. My question is then how to derive the formula in homogeneous coordinates from that definition

Comment: Well, this is *not* the question you posted, is it? I think the viewpoint I've taken is more important for someone working on complex geometry, but you should post this as a separate question. Perhaps I'll think about answering it. Indeed, the right way of looking at *this* question generalizes to Grassmannians quite easily.

Comment: Not exactly, but this was what I had in mind and what led my computations. However you did answer why the invariance I mentioned was not sufficient. Now I would like to understand what is the proper construction